# Issue with SWITCH statement in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

This is my sample code:

```
<?php

$t = 0;

switch( $t )
{
    case 'add':
        echo 'add';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'default';
        break;
}

echo "<br/>";

echo system('php --version');
```

This is the output (tested on codepad.org - result is the same):

```
add
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012 03:26:01) Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I know, it looks stupid, but this situation happened in my ZF app. That $t variable was actually $this->id property which has its parameter from the $_REQUEST array (from url). And this in my case was always string and now I know, that if required param is missed then instead of setting it to an empty string it sets this property to an integer(0)..

Comment: it wasn't sarcasm! i really meant to say it was a good question :)

Comment: It's not. You forgot to describe what you expect to happen instead of what does happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable `$t` has the integer value `0`. With the `switch` statement you tell PHP to compare it first with the value `'add'` (a string). PHP [does this by converting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types) `'add'` to an integer, and due to [the rules of the conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) the result turns out to be `0`.

As a result, the first branch is taken -- which may be surprising, but it's also expected.

You would see the expected behavior if you did

```
$t = "0";
```

Now, both `$t` and `'add'` are strings so there is no magic conversion going on and of course they compare unequal.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, forcing a value to be string solves the issue!

Answer (score 2):

that's because you are comparing an int with an string.. if you force the conversion of 'add' to int it will be 0.. to "fix" your switch statement you can replace

```
switch( $t )
```

to

```
switch( $t . '' )
```

this way telling the server he should use the string value of t (or any other way to achieve this)